# How To Order ActiveRecord Relation Based on Column Of Last Record Of Associated Object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models as below:

```
Client
has_many :cases

Case
belongs_to :client
```

Let say I have 2 clients c1 & c2.
c1 has 1 case, and c2 has 2 cases.

```
c1    = Client.create(name: 'C1')
c2    = Client.create(name: 'C2')
case1 = Case.create(type: 'Normal', client: c1)
case2 = Case.create(type: 'Normal', client: c2)
case3 = Case.create(type: 'High', client: c2)
```

I want to get all clients and order by last case's type of each client asc/desc.
So if I order by asc, I should have the results of 'c1' then c2. And if I order by desc, I should have the results of 'c2' then 'c1'. The following is what I've tried so far.

```
Client.includes(:cases).order('cases.type asc') # => 'C2,C1'
Client.includes(:cases).order('cases.type desc') # => 'C2,C1'
```

Since the c2 also has a case in type 'Normal', I think it seems like the query is finding client first, then it do something like client.cases. Then, I think it orders only cases under each client, and it does not order cases cross client.
I think my explanation is a little bit confusing. Please leave me a question if you have. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try your example with an empty database? I think it works with rails 4. What can happen  is that you get in both cases c2,c1 back because the order of records with the same `type` is not defined. Do you use `type` for STI?  When you use column with the name `type` for other purposes than STI it can create unwanted side effects.

Comment: Thanks @slowjack2k for your comment. I've updated the returning results as it was my mistake previously. Anyway, my problem is that I order either ascending or descending, the results are the same. On the other hand, thanks for mentioning of side effect using 'type' as column name. Actually, my column name is 'case_type', but I just say type as example, and that I forgot about that point. I'm not using it for STI, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the column 'case_type' instead of 'type' because we can not use column type in our table.

To sort the data by case type of last record of client cases please try this.

For ASC

```
Client.includes(:cases).sort_by{|m| m.cases.last.case_type}
```

For DESC

```
 Client.includes(:cases).sort_by{|m| m.cases.last.case_type}.reverse
```

Comment: Thanks @Prashant for your answer. Actually, I've tried like your option, but I got an error when some clients have no cases at all. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Client.all.sort_by{|m| m.cases.present? ? m.cases.last.case_type : "ZZZ"}

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view every thing works fine.
Your order statement only ensures the order of `type` or `case_type`. 
The database can return

```
Normal, C1
Normal, C2
High, C2
```

or

```
Normal, C2
Normal, C1
High, C2
```

for `cases.type asc`

What should happen when `type` is equal you don't specify. Rails will return your objects in the order the database return the records.

If you wan't another order you, you have to specify the order, for instance:

```
Client.includes(:cases).order('cases.type asc, clients.name asc')
```

**Edit:**

To order only on the last depentend record you can use a subselect:

```
Client.select('(SELECT cases.type from cases where cases.client_id=clients.id ORDER BY cases.id desc LIMIT 1) as case_type_name, *').order('case_type_name asc')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default ordcer for a has many association like this:

```
has_many :cases, -> { order 'type asc' }
```

This way, the cases will always be return in order. So you can use sort_by to setup a custom sort on your clients, calling for the last case (and be confident that the cases are ordered), ex:

```
Client.includes(:cases).sort_by { |c| c.cases.last.type }
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe for your answer. Actually, I've tried like your second option, but I got an error when some clients have no cases at all. Any idea to solve this problem?